# 3 textboxes 1 data query mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, if-statement, textbox, runtime-error

Hi im currently new to programming and i chose vb.net and ive encountered this problem where i have 3 textboxes assigned to
 "breed" "name" "age" and i liked to put 2 datas to "breed" "name" "age" and still gets recorded to mysql my code is

```vb
IF txtboxbreed1.txt then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
Elseif txtboxbreed2.text then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
Elseif txtboxbreed3.text then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
```

All i get is a runtime variable brd is used before it has been assigned thank you for help and sorry im typing with my phone the "name" and the "age" is still the same but the "age"  is combobox

Button_add function

```
Dim doggo as new dogclass
Dim breed as new breedclass

Dim fname as string = txtboxfname.text
Dim lname as string = txtboxlname.text
Dim brd as string
Dim name as string
Dim age as string

IF txtboxbreed1.txt then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
Elseif txtboxbreed2.text then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
Elseif txtboxbreed3.text then
    Breed.insertbreed(brd)
End if

If txtboxname1.text And comboboxage1.text then
Doggo.insertdog(name,age)
Elseif txtboxname2.text and comboboxage2.text then Doggo.instertdog(name,age)
Elseif textboxname3.text and comboboxage2.text then doggo.insertdog(name,age)

If verif and person.insertowner(fname,lname) then
Msgbox("yes")
Else
Msgbox ("sorry")
End if
End sub

Function verif as boolean
If txtboxfname.text.trim = " " or (allofthe txtboxes and comboboxes ).text.trim =" "
Else 
Return true
End if
End function

`
CLASSES
`
public function insertowner(byval fname as string ,byval lname as string) as boolean

Using command as new mysqlcommand(" insert into table(fname,lname) values (@fn,@ln),db.Connection" 

Command.parameter.add("@fn",mysqldbtype.varchar).value = fname

Db.connection

If command.executenonquery =  1 then
Return true
Else 
Return false
End if
End using
```

The dogclass(age,name) and breedclass(breed) are the same format and i am stuck in the txtboxbreed1 what should i be putting there for it to be recorded like all of the text box

I copied some code from various source code thank you

Comment: Firstly, that code wouldn't compile for a variety of reasons. If you want us to help you with code that doesn't work then show us that code, not some vague approximation of it. Secondly, the error message you report is telling you exactly what the problem is. Why would you be calling `Breed.insertbreed` and passing the `brd` variable if you haven't actually set the `brd` variable? If you think that you have set it then you're wrong, so you need to show us the rest of the relevant code so we can point out why you're wrong.

Comment: I forgot to add the dim person as ownerclass